# Does Starting Biases affect resources?

Tags: civilization-5

**I know that there are starting biases that affect where a particular civilization is placed**

What I am asking is whether or not this affects the *resources* that surround him. I have noticed that everytime I start as the ***Byzantium*** empire, I always have HEAPS OF SALT :O.

Is this actually a bias, or is every game I played that I am the Byzantium Empire, or the AI/Friend/Enemy is the Byzantium empire is just so lucky to have an abbundence of salt.

Comment: As @aytimothy has stated, it's most likely that you're playing the same map settings since Byzantine has a Coastal bias which is more likely to improve your chances of Whales, Pearls, Crabs, etc. Salt is most likely to spawn near Desert or Tundra areas so it would be merely a coincidence that you have been getting them every time.

Comment: Salt is also one of the better luxury resources, in terms of the bonuses it gives you.

Answer (score 2):

In Civilization 5, staring resources are determined by the map seed. It is most likely that you've been playing with the same map settings... and seed over and *over*.. Or *luck*.

As for surrounding terrain placement/spawn location - That IS biased to each empire (but can be disabled in advanced settings).

---

I've created about 10 games, none but one contained salt.